# How setting -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=12001 property in eclipse.ini opens Microsoft Edge 20?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, microsoft-edge

I am currently working on a eclipse RCP application and using SWT. As the default browser for windows is IE (which has so many issues) we wanted to use some other browser.While chrome is out of scope for now as per this [link](https://medium.com/@mikael.barbero/chromium-eclipse-swt-integration-c61f416e97d1) I checked this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093905/).
I don't get it how IE which uses a different engine(MSHTML) can open edge which uses EdgeHTML engine.The version of edge which gets open is Edge 20 which is the first version of Edge browser.Is there any way to use the recent version of edge using some property like above?